# Perl regex | Match second from the right

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to parse an OID and extract the #18 but I am unsure on how to write it to count Right to Left using a dot as a delimiter:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.10035
```

This regex will grab the last value

```
my $ifindex = ($_=~ /^.*[.]([^.]*)$/);
```

I haven't found a way to tweak it to get the value I need yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is simpler:

```
my $ifindex;

if (/(\d+)\.\d+$/)
{
   $ifindex = $1;
}
```

A couple of comments:

1. You don't need to match the entire string, only the part you care about.  Thus, no need to anchor to the beginning with `^` and use `.*`.  Anchor to the end only.
2. `[.]` is a character class, intended for matching groups of characters.  e.g., `[abc]` will match either a, b, or c.  It should be avoided when matching a single character; just match that character instead.  In this case you do need to escape it, since it is a special character: `\.`.
3. I have assumed based on your example that all of the terms have to be numbers.  Hence, I used `\d+` for the terms.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
my $str = "1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.10035";
say ((split(/\./, $str))[-2]);
```

**output:**

```
18
```

Comment: @preaction, `split` is certainly an acceptable approach, but I wouldn't call it "absolutely the correct way".  When you only need a single value out of the string, a regex would be faster and use less memory.

Comment: Except that regular expressions are more difficult to read and thus more prone to bugs. Performance (at this level) is rarely a concern; if it was you'd use index() and substr().

Answer (score 3):

If the format is always the same (ie. always second from right) then you can either use:-

```
m/(\d+)\.\d+$/;
```

..and the answer will end up in: `$1`

Or a different approach would be to split the string into an array on the dots and examine the penultimate value in the array.

Comment: TIL the definition of penultimate - Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

```
my $ifindex = ($_=~ /^.*[.]([^.]*)[.][^.]*$/);
```